# Find code between two lines

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to get an alert when a certain code is between two specific lines.

Here is the code:

```
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
      swiffyobject, {});
        stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%");
  stage.start();
```

Is there a way to open the webpage and showing an alert if

`stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%");"`

is in the code and not if it is between

`swiffyobject, {});`    and   `stage.start();`?

Comment: Probably not! Why would you want to do this? Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). (Also, pedant alert - thats not "JQuery code" its just plain old "Javascript")

Comment: Would it not be simpler check an attribute on the page and if it is true then create an alert message?

Example: You put a data-TreuOrFalse= ServerVariable

And when the page has loaded check this data attribute and depending on the value create an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this script is inside page but not in external script (other file than the page file) you can do like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var script = $('script:contains(var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById)');
  alert(script.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
      swiffyobject, {});
        stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%");
  stage.start();
</script>
```

For the second check, you need to use `Regex` and it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running your code in a browser env. I guess there's no easy way for you to do that. You can however:

- Decorate `stage.setFlashVars` with your implementation and intercept whether the method has been called with a specific parameter value. This will however not tell you if the code is executed before stage.start() or not.
- If your code is included in a `script` tag in the page, you can select that script tag, read its content and parse it (quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9vudjwba/).

Both approaches looks really overkill to me. What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?